# Finding the second integral of the 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, math, numerical-methods

I have the following 2D array:

```
N = 6

M = np.zeros((N,N))
for i in range(N-1):
    for j in range(N-1):
        if i==0 or j==0:
            M[i,j] = 0
        else:
            M[i,j] = 1
```

Basically, it is the array of zeros on the sides and ones in the middle.

I want to calculate the following integral:

[image]

So, I use the code below:

```
dx=dy=d=1
My, Mx = np.gradient(M, d, d)

Lx = 0
p = 1/(M.shape[0]*M.shape[1])
for i in range(N-1):
    for j in range(N-1):
        Lx += p*math.sqrt(1+(Mx[i,j])**2)*dx*dy
```

However, the value that I am getting out of the calculations is not the matching the one it should be:
My answer: 0.77
Correct answer: 0.98

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: The variables `d`, `dx`, and `dy` are undefined in your code.

Comment: I forgot to add them here, will edit it now. Basically, `dx=dy=d` are the spacings between points. In this case, they are all equal to `1`

Comment: It looks like 0.77 is the correct answer to the sequence of operations you are doing. Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: I was thinking whether my iteration is a correct representation of the double integral?